# How does the superposition principle relate to Bernoulli-Euler and Timoshenko beam theory?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam, modeling

I have a shaft with a bearing in each end, and a large eccentric mass covering the entire "free length" of the shaft.

[image]

The attachment of the eccentric mass is done using heat shrinking.

Without bearings:

[image]

Without bearings and eccentric masses:

[image]

I need to calculate deflection equations $y_{ab}$ ($x\in\{0,a\}$, from outmost left to left hand side of flywheel), $y_{BC}$ ($x\in\{a,b\}$, from left hand side of flywheels to right hand side of flywheels), and $y_{CD}$ ($x\in\{b,l\}$, from right hand side of flywheels to outmost right):

[image]

This is similar to Shigley's Mechanical Engineering Design problem 4-19, 10$^{th}$ ed.:

FBD:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by how do they relate to Euler-Bernoulli? You say you used superposition to derive those equations, so what did you derive them from? Or did you just copy this from a textbook and are unsure as to whether it uses EB or Timoshenko?

Comment: I don't understand what the deflections have to do with this. If the eccentric mass is shrink-fitted, to any reasonable approximation most of the shaft is a rigid body, not a beam. The only parts that will behave anything like a "beam" have $l/r \approx 1.0$, from your pictures.

Comment: "How can I test it?" Make it, stand well back, and spin it. Be careful it doesn't make a hole in the floor, wall, or ceiling when it breaks! (Making a hole in *you* is an even worse outcome, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Your mechanism is rigid between the points B-C. Using w as uniform load is meaningless; uniform load Is best imagined as the pressure of a liquid to the bottom of its container.

For this case you need to check both vertical and torque shear at the start and end of eccentric mass. And you need to plot the shear stresses on a Mohr circle to calculate the principal stresses and axis.

This mechanism looks like its designed to counter another off balance flywheel. If so, then you need to calculate the dynamic vibration and dangerous resonance frequencies of the system and its response spectra.

There are many FEM systems that can do that. Important point is you are looking at the problem in a totally wrong angle.

Comment: I would not say that it is "rigid" between B-C, but it is certainly significantly stiffer than the OP is presuming.

Comment: @kamran. Modeling it with a center point load would be worse. So what would the alternative to a uniform load be?

You are correct about assuming the mechanism to counterbalance a flywheel. Vibration analysis will also be done (and using FEM as you propose), but this is another and subsequent analysis.